# Running ExtJS app in Internet Explorer

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Though i removed trailing comma, in my mvc project, it's not loading in IE 8. Can building this app for deployment resolve this issue ?  I'm not sure why this issue occurs

Comment: you need to be more specific, what errors do you get ?

Comment: undefined is null or not an object

Comment: you should have a stack trace of where the error occurred.

Comment: The above error is occurring in ext-all.js

Comment: you have just defined a normal extjs error, you can replace ext-all.js with ext-all-debug.js which isn't minified and then set breakpoints where it fails. you have to see what component fails and when (posibly during layout calculation, ie8 being very strict about the html structure generated).

Comment: I fixed all the issues, i'm not getting any error, but the components are rendering too slowly, even sometimes showing "A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive". Anything i can do with ExtJS ?  The same code works without any such messages in FF, Chrome.

Comment: That's nothing unusual , extjs 4 (also extjs in general) has performance problems in ie. I'm guessing you are using 4.0.x They claimed they solved 'some' problems in 4.1, you can check the charts in this link http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-developer-preview/ , but nevertheless, try without your developer tools open, because that slows ie a lot. Most problems for ie is due to the layout so, a try to keep your dom to a minimum, by destroying unused components. Cheers, hope it helps